# UI in aws ubuntu 16.04 for kubernetes dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04

I set up kubernetes environment in aws ec2(ubuntu 16.04) instances. There is one master and two slaves. I have created the dashboard in the master node, to access it i required web based UI. I tried to install gnome environment in ec2 instance, but its not working. Is there any other way to access the dashboard of kubernetes or setting up web-UI in aws ec2 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the AWS documentation:

> This [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dashboard-tutorial.html) guides you through deploying the Kubernetes
>   dashboard to your Amazon EKS cluster, complete with CPU and memory
>   metrics. It also helps you to create an Amazon EKS administrator
>   service account that you can use to securely connect to the dashboard
>   to view and control your cluster.

EDIT:
Check out those guides:

- [Kubernetes Visualizer](https://schoolofdevops.github.io/ultimate-kubernetes-bootcamp/kube_visualizer/)
- [How to Visualize Docker & Kubernetes](https://medium.com/@elliot.kim/visualize-your-kubernetes-cluster-a87f1cafb6fe)
- [Setting up Kubernetes visualization of a cluster](https://kubecloud.io/setting-up-kubernetes-visualization-of-a-cluster-96826433fc64)

They will help you learn about and setup a Visualizer.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hi Mark, am not using EKS cluster. Am using only amazon EC2 ubuntu instances. From that i have create one maser, two slaves machines for the kubernetes set-up. All set-up is done for kubernetes except with dashboard. In EC2 istances UI is not there, i have to access that dashboard remotely.

Comment: So what you need is Visualizer. I will update my answer with the info regarding it in a minute. Please check it out and let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hi mark, thanks for the links. Kubernetes Visualizer link is worked. :)